# The Difference Between Time Clauses

Tags: clauses, time

I was pleased **as/after/when/whenever** I heard the news.

Could you please tell me if they are all correct? If yes what is the difference between them?

Comment: tell us why you think they are correct/incorrect and what you think the differences are

Comment: I know 'when' is correct but I don't know if others are correct and I don't know the difference between them either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pleased whenever I heard the news means that you heard the news more than once and you were pleased every time.

I was pleased after I heard the news means you heard the news first and afterwards you were pleased.

I was pleased as I heard the news means that being pleased and hearing the news occurred at the same time.

I was pleased when I heard the news means you were pleased very shortly after you heard the news and you were pleased because of it. In my opinion this is the correct choice.

Comment: Thank you very much.